# UPDATE TABLE WITH CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update, case

I have two tables `user_master` and `login_history`. 
In `User_master` I want to update the `status` column as **A(absent)** or **P(Present)** if user has logged in in current date from login history.
the code I am trying but it updates all the rows. All I want is if the user has logged in , it should match both the tables and update `user_master`  `status` column as **P** or **A**. 
Hope My question is clear. Help would be really appreciated. here is my MySQL query

```
 UPDATE User_master a
 INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_name FROM login_history  WHERE DATE(`login_time`)=CURRENT_DATE()
  ) b

SET a.`user_status` = CASE 
   WHEN a.`user_name`=B.`user_name` THEN 'P'
   WHEN a.`user_name`!=B.`user_name` THEN 'A'
 END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, I am thinking `LEFT JOIN`:

```
UPDATE User_master m
LEFT JOIN Login_History lh
    ON m.user_name = lh.user_name AND
       DATE(lh.login_time) = CURRENT_DATE()
SET m.user_status = (CASE WHEN lh.user_name IS NULL THEN 'A' ELSE 'P' END);
```

It occurs to me that there might be more than one login on a given date.  The result is additional updates on the same row.  You can prevent this by doing:

```
UPDATE User_master m LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT lh.user_name, 'P' as user_status
        FROM Login_History lh
        WHERE lh.login_time >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
              lh.login_tie < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        GROUP BY lh.user_name
       ) lh
       ON m.user_name = lh.user_name 
    SET m.user_status = COALESCE(lh.user_status, 'A');
```

Notice that I changed the date arithmetic as well.  This version should make better use of an index.

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier with two queries:

1. Set everyone absent (update ... set user_status='A')
2. Set the present people to P with a select set.

Like so:

```
update user_master set user_status='A';

update user_master set user_status='P'
where user_name in (select distinct user_name from login_history...);
```

A join is somewhat quicker, but this is a pretty clean, understandable approach.